# Will we participate in Winterbash this year?

Tags: discussion

Will we be participating in Winterbash this year? If the community wants to opt-out, the mods would need to let the CM team know by December 13th.

Answer (score 2):

I say let's opt-in. Hats are fun.

Comment: Absolutely! I have always been a fan of hats.